# Prevent Go's json.Marshal from coercing string to valid UTF-8 unicode?

Tags: go

I'm trying to POST some JSON to a server using Go where special characters like ampersand must exist intact in the JSON string I'm sending.

http://play.golang.org/p/bPt9kl88-y

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {

    type TransactionStatement struct {
        Query      string                 
    }

    statement := &TransactionStatement{
        Query:       "my query with this & that",
    }
    data, _ := json.Marshal(statement)

    fmt.Printf("> %v", string(data))
}
```

Go's [json.Marshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) is converting certain characters like '&' to unicode.  Which is great:

> String values encode as JSON strings coerced to valid UTF-8, replacing invalid bytes with the Unicode replacement rune. The angle brackets "<" and ">" are escaped to "\u003c" and "\u003e" to keep some browsers from misinterpreting JSON output as HTML. Ampersand "&" is also escaped to "\u0026" for the same reason. 
>   Blockquote

It may sound rediculous but the JSON I'm sending is for a database query using a RESTful endpoint, where this literal string will be used to perform a freetext database query - so I can't use unicode since it's interpreted literally.

So is there any way to prevent this conversion to unicode? Or will I just have to undo these replacements *after* the marshaling is done?

Thanks

Comment: It may look strange, but are you certain this is actually a problem? Most json decoders should handle that correctly.

Comment: Well it's not a problem per se, it becomes a problem when one needs to keep certain characters intact when sending smth over the wire.

Comment: What I'm saying is that this is correct json, and the json decoder on the other end of the wire should unescape those characters correctly. If not, you need to replace the characters manually after encoding; `bytes.Replace` would be the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You're right.  I just realized after posting other characters are getting encoded to unicode as well and those are indeed working.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized after posting other characters are getting encoded to unicode as well and those are indeed working.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose not to encode if you wish:
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.SetEscapeHTML

https://play.golang.org/p/gfy1WaDrEIH